# Como dividir uma `string` e depois converter para int?

Tags: java

Eu tenho uma string "1 2 3 4 5" para dividi-la e guardar os números em variáveis separadas eu estava lendo e vi que tem que usar um método chamado Split... Eu tentei fazer, mas não consegui.

Como faço isso, e depois como faço para converter para int os resultados para que eu possa, por exemplo somar todos os números?? Resumindo: Quero saber como converter uma String array inteira em uma int array. O código que deu erro foi esse:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = ("1 2 3 4 5");
    String array[] = new String[5];
    int resultado[] = new String[5];
    array = x.split (" ");
            System.out.println(resultado[0]+resultado[1]+resultado[2]+resultado[3]+resultado[4]);
}
```

}

Comment: Mostre o que você fez e podemos dizer mais facilmente onde você está errando. Esta é a melhor ajuda que podemos dar. Se entregarmos pronto, não estamos ajudando, estamos fazendo por você.

Comment: Provavelmente "guardar em variáveis separadas" não é bem o que você quer. Se a string vier com 10 números você vai guardar em 10 variáveis? Se vier com 100 números, 100 variáveis? Como você vai escrever código para acessar essas variáveis depois? Etc. O método [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) de fato é o que você precisa (se esse for o objetivo da pergunta, sugiro [edit] a mesma esclarecendo isso, então poderemos explicar melhor seu funcionamento). Você já sabe como trabalhar com *arrays*?

Comment: Melhor opção usa split e joga dentro e um array esses valores depois é só trabalhar com ele.

Comment: Então, já sei sim trabalhar com arrays, e é isso que estava usando no programa. Eu consigo usar o Split, mas depois não consigo converte-lo para int...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Algumas considerações em relação ao seu código:

1. Você não precisa declarar e instanciar um vetor para receber o retorno do Split. O próprio Split já instancia e retorna um array do tipo String para você. Portanto, você precisa apenas da declaração.

   `String array[] = x.split (" ");`
2. Você está tentando atribuir a um vetor do tipo int (resultado[]) um vetor do tipo String. Isso vai dar erro de compilação, já que java é uma linguagem fortemente tipada.
3. Para realizar a conversão você pode usar a seguinte abordagem, veja:

   `int resultado[] = new int[5];
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       resultado[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
   }`

O código acima utilizou o método estático **parseInt** da classe **Integer** para converter uma String em um Inteiro.